# Angular 14 get data from unrelated component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I need help with understanding data sharing between components... I have a project that has a cart page and a footer that is a standalone component and is included in every page of my app... In the footer I have a cart icon and on that icon I'm trying to show the number of items in cart... I get the data of items in cart from an API... Do I have to call this api and all of its data in the footer component with the same function as in the cart page also or is there a shorter simpler way that uses less code?

In the image bellow you can see this footer component *(**NOTE: 11 is hardcoded at the moment**)*:
[image]

Here is the the API response how the cart data looks like:

```
{
    "total_products": 0,
    "totals": null,
    "notes": null,
    "shipping_method": null,
    "products": []
}
```

Here is the code of cart.page.ts that I use to show data in my app:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCart();
  }

  getCart() {
    this.getCartSubscription = this.cartService.getCart().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        const productsData = data.body.products;
        const totalProducts = data.body.total_products;
        const totalCartPrice = data.body.totals;
        this.products = productsData.map(products => products);
        this.totalProducts = totalProducts;
        this.totalCartPrice = totalCartPrice;
        console.log('Products in cart:', data.body);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  }
```

How do I approach to showing total products in my footer component?

Is my code even good? Is there a way to optimize it? This is my first real Angular project and I would like to do this as propperly as possible :)

****EDIT:** I have read about and tried using BehaviourSubject but am unsure of it implementation in my case...

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Use **BehaviorSubject**. It is the simplest way in angular to share data between unrelated component.

https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/infragistics/posts/simplest-way-to-share-data-between-two-unrelated-components-in-angular

https://medium.com/codex/how-to-share-data-between-components-in-angular-a-shopping-cart-example-b86ce8254965

Comment: Thank you for this, I have been looking at BehaviourSubject... altho I think I dont know how to propperly implement it in my case but I will read into it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could decorate the page-component with [`@Output`](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) and the footer with [`@Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input). See [this page on angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

I've created a [simple example you can find on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/output-input-demo). However, I think as your application grows it will be better just to use [a service the call the backend](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) (as you are doing in your `cart`-component) and have all interested component subscibe to it.

Comment: Could you provide an example pleaase? I'm not realy sure how to propperly implement behaviour subject

Comment: I've only got an example in Dutch. But [this blog](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-input-output-eventemitter/) seems to describe the workings quite well.